# target the last hr within repeating div

Tags: html, css

I have a section that has a repeating div coming from the database and within there there is an hr to separate them, but I need to hide the last one in the list.

So my html looks like this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="reply">
    <p>wonderful paragraph</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="reply">
    <p>wonderful paragraph</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="reply">
    <p>wonderful paragraph</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried targeting with last-child a few different ways, but I cant seem to get it right.

```
.container:last-child .reply hr{
  display:none;
}

.reply:last-child hr{
  display:none;
}

.container .reply:last-child hr{
  display:none;
}
```

Any help would be wonderful!

the styles I have on my hr

```
.reply hr{
  border: 0;
      height: 1px;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
      background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
      background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
      background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: The last and the second last will work

Comment: I cannot get the last or second to last to work at all...hence my question.

Comment: Could you use borders instead of hrs?

Comment: no, I cannot. I have specific styles for the hr that cannot be applied to borders.

Answer (score 3):

Use this -- it will hide your last reply div:

```
jQuery(".reply").last().hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

The last and the second last will work. As they select the last child with class `reply` in the `container`. The `<hr>` within this container will then be hidden.

```
.reply:last-child hr {
    display:none;
}

.container .reply:last-child hr {
    display:none;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/cZFSr/) (Version 1)

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/qZSZf/) (Version 2)

**The first one**

```
.container:last-child .reply hr {
    display:none;
}
```

is going to hide all `<hr>`-elements if `div.container` is the last child of its parent element.

Comment: I cannot get this to work in my site. It's not hiding anything.

Comment: Do you have a link? It seems, that some other styles are overwriting your rules here. Important is also how the `<hr>`-element is styled.

Comment: I dont have a live link, I'm working in a company that wont allow my to put exact html or any kind of code on the internet. and I have tried the important rule that should have worked, but its not.

Comment: Can you at least post the full CSS for `container` and its children? Are there any inline styles? Is there really no other element after the last `reply` (like a `<span>` or something)? Do you have something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BWyDa/) that breaks it?

Comment: I'll post the only styles I have going on above...it's really only to make the hr look pretty.

Comment: So the `hr`-styles aren't the problem. What about my other questions? And are there other `<hr>`-elements styled in your CSS? And what **browser** and which **version** are you testing?

Comment: There are no other styles being applied to the p tags or to the container....and these are the only hr's on the page so far.

Comment: and I am testing in Chrome, Safari and Firefox all the latest versions.

Comment: OK, thought it might be IE8 where `last-child` would be problematic.

Comment: I just tried adding it in the web inspector to see if that would work, but it's not working there either.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container .reply:last-child hr {
    display: none;
}
```

Grab the last `.reply` and hide any `hr` elements within that.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9HNNU/

Comment: Yes, I have. This is one of the things I tried first. I have even thrown in an !important and it didn't effect it at all.

Comment: Yes, and it works in the fiddle, but then when placed in actual html it fails to work.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/WxkDh/)

```
div.reply:last-child hr{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container .reply:last-child hr {display:none;}
```

First select that last repeating div, then select it's child hr tag and display none on that element. If there is more than one hr tag within each repeating div, you could add an additional last-child pseudo class to the hr selector.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NuuAa/